# Migrating from the Grails UI-performance plugin to resources plugin

Tags: grails

I am trying to install resources plugin in my project.
I am confused where I should put the this code.

see this page [resource plugin](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/migrating-from-the-grails-ui-performance-plugin-to-resources-plugin/)

```
package com.flashsales.utils

// maps UI Performance tags to resources plugin tags
class ConvertUiPerformanceTagLib {

    static namespace = 'p'

    def css = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = "/css/${ attrs.remove( 'name' ) }.css"
        attrs.type = 'css'
        out << r.external( attrs )    }   def image = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = '/images' + attrs.remove( 'src' )
        out << r.img( attrs )     }   def javascript = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = "/js/${ attrs.remove( 'src' ) }.js"
        attrs.type = 'js'
        out << r.external( attrs )
    }

    //  TODO: imageLink, favicon, inputImage, sprite, dependantJavascript and addJavaScript

}
```

I have already done step 1 and 2 and stuck at step 3.

Comment: I guess into the `tagLib` folder of your project

Comment: sorry,, please see my edit,  i inserted the link

Comment: Put it in your tag lib folder and change the package name accordingly to your project's structure.

Comment: can i know where's tag lib folder?

Comment: did you mean grails-app/taglib?

Comment: Just to be sure, you know that the resources plugin is replaced with the asset pipeline plugin with the latest release of Grails? Maybe that's not an option for you, but I'm telling you in case you missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a file at grails -app/taglib/sample.groovy

with this code

```
class ConvertUiPerformanceTagLib {

    static namespace = 'p'

    def css = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = "/css/${ attrs.remove( 'name' ) }.css"
        attrs.type = 'css'
        out << r.external( attrs )    }   def image = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = '/images' + attrs.remove( 'src' )
        out << r.img( attrs )     }   def javascript = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = "/js/${ attrs.remove( 'src' ) }.js"
        attrs.type = 'js'
        out << r.external( attrs )
    }
```

this code is use for read your tag. example : `<p:img src="" / >` or css etc

so when you use `<p:img src="" />`

it will execute this first

```
def css = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = "/css/${ attrs.remove( 'name' ) }.css"
        attrs.type = 'css'
        out << r.external( attrs )    }   def image = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = '/images' + attrs.remove( 'src' )
        out << r.img( attrs )     }   def javascript = { attrs ->
        attrs.uri = "/js/${ attrs.remove( 'src' ) }.js"
        attrs.type = 'js'
        out << r.external( attrs )
    }
```